# Почему создание новой функции работает только в Mozilla?

Tags: jquery, функции, javascript

Почему код работает только в мозиле?

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
alert('m2');

var chFormI = 2; //общая проверка формы 2-можно , 3-запрет

//Создаю новую функцию
function chekForm (name, ch = 1){
    if (name.val() =='') { 
            name.next().show("slow");
            name.parent() .addClass('has-error');   
            if (ch==2)  {chFormI=3;}     
         }  else {
            name.next().hide("slow");
            name.parent() .removeClass('has-error');
         }

}

}); // $(document).ready /
```

Вот код в "песочнице" http://jsbin.com/kumiyebahazu/1/edit,
проблема именно вот в этом:

```
//Создаю новую функцию
    function chekForm (name, ch = 1){
        if (name.val() =='') { 
                name.next().show("slow");
                name.parent() .addClass('has-error');   
                if (ch==2)  {chFormI=3;}     
             }  else {
                name.next().hide("slow");
                name.parent() .removeClass('has-error');
             }

    }
```

Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: В js нельзя определять аргументы по умолчанию, как в php, то есть ch = 1 замените на ch.

Answer (score 4):

Вы неправильно задаете значение аргумента функции по умолчанию. Правильно будет в самой функции писать:

```
var ch = сh || 1;
```

Comment: Ваш код тоже не работал в мозиле. Решил задачу:

 if (ch === undefined) {
    ch = 1;
  }

Comment: @Максим147, а вы заменили ch = 1 в определении функции на ch?

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу:

if (ch === undefined) {
    ch = 1;
  }